# Underline a specific text string on multiple Word docs

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to bulk edit a folder of Word docs? Specifically, I need one specific word underlined in all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the information here [Beginning with PowerShell and Word](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/12/31/beginning-with-powershell-and-word/).

Comment: There is nothing about underlining text in this link. Only bolding or italicizing.

Comment: Underline is the same thing as bolding or italicizing - just another  font style.